# SharePoint 2016 Small HA MinRole Farm Disk Requirements

Tags: 2016, minrole

I'm wanting to deploy a new SharePoint 2016 Small High Availability MinRole Farm to house and manage 2,000+ SSRS reports:

Four servers with two shared roles:

- Two Front-end with Distributed Cache servers
- Two Application with Search servers

Two Microsoft SQL servers (configured as a failover cluster for High Availability).

I'm having difficulty estimating the number of disks required for this set-up. I've estimated 24 for the MinRole set up (System / Data / Log) but this seems high.

Does anyone have any disk estimation experience for the above MinRole configuration?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to estimate RAID requirements and is this for one server or all servers? Is this a SAN or individual physical machines? SharePoint itself doesn't take much room, and the SSRS reports themselves are tiny.

Comment: Hi Trevor - no, not trying to estimate RAID requirements. Simply trying to set up a new small high availability SP2016 MinRole Farm for SSRS reporting. Microsoft suggest a minimum of 4 servers with 2 shared roles + 2 x SQL servers. I'm trying to estimate the number of disks required for the 4 servers with shared roles on SAN.